# Passing a value from one case to another in switch statement

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, return-value, scope

So here is a sample code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please type in a number");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    switch (in.nextInt()){
        case 1:
            save(in);
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println(value);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Default case");
            break;
    }               
    in.close();
}

public static String save(Scanner in){
System.out.println("Type in a word");
String value = in.next();
return value;
}
}
```

In this particular situation all I am trying to do here is to have access to the `value` that was stored in case 1.

Comment: Show your code so far.

Comment: Please write down what you have to do clearly - that will go a long way towards solving your problem. By the sound of it, the switch statement is particularly relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`switch` statement in all c-like languages including java is very general. It jumps to label according to the value of switch variable and then continues until `break` statement appears.

I am not sure what did you meant in your long explanation but in following example:

```
switch(op) {
    case ONE:
        foo();
    case TWO:
        bar();
        break;
    case THREE:
        aaa();
        qqq();
        break;
}
```

`op == ONE` first method `foo()` will be called, then the flow will arrive to block of `TWO` because no break statement was written in `ONE`, so `bar()` will be called. However then the break statement will jump the flow to code that appears just after the switch.

This is a short explanation. For more details find a good book or tutorial and read chapter about switch statement.