# Can we call a "case" inside another case in the same switch statement in Java?

Tags: java, switch-statement

My intention is to call two cases inside another case in the same switch statement,

```
switch (orderType) {
        case 1: 
            statement 1;
            break;
       case 2:
            statement 2;
            break;
       case 3:
             **call case 1;**
             **Call case 2;**
             break;
       default:
            break;`
}
```

Can we do that in Java?

Comment: I don't think so, why you want to do it ?

Comment: Using "switch-case" meant to make your code easier to understand, don't try to over complicate it.

Comment: Relevant [Passing a value from one case to another in switch statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621708/passing-a-value-from-one-case-to-another-in-switch-statement)

Comment: @MarounMaroun I'm puzzled. You closed the question as a duplicate of a question dealing with _nested_ switch-case-statements. But this question is about code reusage of another case in the _same_ switch. Or did I understand this wrong?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I reopened, though the answer for this question is very similar.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I agree about the similarity of the answers, and I think that would have been a good reason for closing this one. I just thought, it's not really a duplicate ...

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose You're right and thanks for the comment. I didn't pay enough attention.

Comment: Hm, there's a downvote but this question seems fine and valid to me. Not quite useful but yeah.

Comment: I guess you can put case 3:  before case 1: and case 2. In case 3:   remove the break;  and add  orderType=1. This will cause case 1: to be executed. It is NOT a nice solution and I would try yo avoid it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although you cannot influence the `switch` cases directly, you can call switch's parent method from one case and pass different arguments. For example,

```
void foo(int param1, String param2, ...) {
    switch (param1) {
        case 0:
            foo(1, "some string");
            break;

        case 1:
            //do something
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

No, you can't *jump* to the code snippet in another switch case. You can however extract the code into an own method that can be called from another case:

```
switch (orderType) {
    case 1: 
        someMethod1();
        break;
    case 2:
        someMethod2();
        break;
    case 3:
        someMethod1();
        someMethod2();
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

void someMethod1() { ... }
void someMethod2() { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't just call a another `case` block like this. What you could do, though, is wrap each of these blocks in a method, and reuse them:

```
private void doSomething() {
    // implementation
}

private void doSomethingElse() {
    // implementation
}

private void runSwitch(int order) {

    switch (orderType) {
           case 1: 
                doSomething();
                break;
           case 2:
                doSomethingElse();
                break;
           case 3:
                doSomething();
                doSomethingElse();
                break;
           default:
                break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using methods is the best way to do it as mentioned in the accepted answer but for some reasons if you are unable to create method, Here is one more way to do this without using methods

```
boolean isBreakTheLoop = false, isCase2Required = false;
while(!isBreakTheLoop){
    switch (orderType) {
       case 1: 
            statement 1;
            if(isCase2Required){
               orderType = 2;
               break;
            }
            isBreakTheLoop = true;
            break;
       case 2:
            statement 2;
            isBreakTheLoop = true;
            break;
       case 3:
            orderType = 1;
            isCase2Required = true;
            break;
       default:
            isBreakTheLoop = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder: while the most suggested case is the best solution, note that if you don't close with a `brake;` your `case:`, it will continue executing in the next case.

Then, while it's still best pratice to break your cases, you could still adopt a solution similar to the following:

```
switch (orderType) {
    case 3:
        someMethod1();
    case 2:
        someMethod2();
        break;
    case 1: 
        someMethod1();
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Note that "avoiding breaks" solution can't completely cover OP necessities, because writing:

```
    case 3:
    case 1:
        someMethod1();
    case 2:
        someMethod2();
    default:
        break;
```

or:

```
    case 3:
    case 1:
        someMethod1();
        break;
    case 2:
        someMethod2();
        break;
    default:
        break;
```

would make `case: 3` be the same than `case: 1`, making them execute both methods in first code, or a single method in the second code.

Comment: This was already proposed 4 years ago, see below.

Comment: The case from 4 years ago was very generical and like saying it could totally fullfill OP needs.
My post explain it is an alternative, but limited as solution. And it explains why.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this trick in some case :

```
switch (orderType) {
   case 3: 
        statement 3;
   case 2:
        statement 2;
   case 1:
        statement 1;
        break;
   default:
        break;`
```

}

Comment: Your answer does not address the question